# Menu tabs disappear if clicking on custom tab

Tags: users, routes

I am adding a custom menu tab to a user profile. That works fine, but once I click on the tab the other menu tabs (edit, view, etc.) disappear. How can I keep the other menu tabs?

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/inbox'] = array(
    'title' => t('inbox'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('messages'),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```